# Scala case class: generating Instances for type constructor cases?

Tags: scala, case-class, type-constructor

I want to use a generic function that returns the "default value" for a given type. I have implemented this with the help of the following case class construct:

```
case class DefaultOp[T](op: () => T)
implicit val defaultString = DefaultOp[String](() => "")
implicit val defaultInt = DefaultOp[Int](() => 0)
implicit val defaultFloat = DefaultOp[Float](() => 0.0f)
implicit val defaultDouble = DefaultOp[Double](() => 0.0d)
// ...

def default[T]()(implicit ev: DefaultOp[T]): T = ev.op()
```

That works fine, but I would like to extend it to also work on Types constructed from a type constructor. For instance, I would like to be the default value for any option type to be "None" and for any list type to be Nil. How can I implementd this? My first attemt:

```
implicit val defaultOption = DefaultOp[Option[_]](() => None)
```

compiles, but it does not compile when I use it in an application:

```
error: could not find implicit value for parameter ev: DefaultOp[Option[Float]]
var test: Option[Float] = default[Option[Float]]
                                  ^
one error found
```

Any suggestion how this can be made working?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `Option[Float]` is not a `Option[_]`, because we don't know what `_` is supposed to be.

You can solve this by making `defaultOption` a def, and using a type parameter:

```
implicit def defaultOption[A] = DefaultOp[Option[A]](() => None)

scala> default[Option[Float]]
res3: Option[Float] = None
```

Comment: Thanks! That's it. I was not aware of the fact that I can use a function definition instead of a val ... that leads to the next question: What is the principal differnce between implicit def defaultDouble = DefaultOp[Double](() => 0.0d) and implicit val defaultDouble = DefaultOp[Double](() => 0.0d)? Which one is preferable and why?

Comment: The only difference is that one is a def, and the other is a val. For `defaultDouble`, using a val is fine because it's never going to change. However, for a generic type. a def is required because you need to be able to generate implicits for (possibly) any type.

Comment: Note also that a `def` will create a new instance of `DefaultOp` for every invocation. If this is on your critical path, you may not want this. You can then cheat with this code: `private val reusableDefaultOption = DefaultOp[Option[Nothing]](() => None); implicit def defaultOption[A] = reusableDefaultOption.asInstanceOf[DefaultOp[Option[A]]]`.